# How to use "geometryEngine" in arcGIS Version 3.9

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geometry

We are using arcGIS javascript version 3.9 in our portal. Now we have new requirement to do reverse clipping on map. We have already written code to implement reverse clipping with the help of "esri/geometry/geometryEngine". The issue is that "esri/geometry/geometryEngine" was introduced in 3.13 and we are using 3.9 in our portal. When we try to load

```
require(["esri/geometry/geometryEngine"], function(geometryEngine) { /* code goes here */ });
```

in version 3.9, it gives error.
Is there any way to use "esri/geometry/geometryEngine" in version 3.9.

Comment: No, there's no way to use functionality introduced at JSAPI 3.13 with 3.9.  You'd have to use the 3.9 solution, of using an SOE or geoprocessing service to manipulate the geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vince is right.  when you need functionality that was introduced in a specific release of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript (or any API for that matter) the only way to get access to it is to utilize the version where its present.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/new_v313.html